# Adding Microsoft.Phone.dll to use Applicationbar class gives "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll" error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1. After I add the Microsoft.Phone.dll assembly to be able to use the ApplicationBar and ApplicationBarIconButton classes, I encounter the following
error:

`Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll.`

After reading about similar problems (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722608/cannot-find-type-system-systemexception-in-module-mscorlib-dll-when-i-referenc)), it seems that Windows Phone does not accept third parties libraries.

How am I supposed to use the aforementioned classes in my C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Phone.dll` old style (Silverlight) Windows Phone Library.
In usual Windows Phone Store Application you should use `CommandBar` component.

Sample: [How it works](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/appbarcommand-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1/)

**UPDATE**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="bottomCommandBar">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Account"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

and C# code

```
    private bool _isAdded;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isAdded)
        {
            var button = new AppBarButton();
            button.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Find);
            bottomCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(button);
        }
        else
        {
            bottomCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.RemoveAt(bottomCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Count - 1);
        }

        _isAdded = !_isAdded;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the refererence, could you also provide a c# code reference on this?

Comment: you want add command bar programatically (via c#)? not in xaml?

Comment: Well, not only this, I need to change programmaticaly the buttons in the app and I would be able to change the properties of the commandbar and the buttons via c#.

Comment: Thank you very much for your courtesy.